# Add class to second list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to the second list element of an unordered list but its not working even though I can add the same class to the first list element, could someone please tell me where Im going wrong, many thanks in advance!

```js
var url = "http://myshop.com/about-us/"; // window.location.href;
if (url == 'https://myshop.com/') {
  $("ul.menu.low li a:first").addClass("active white");
}
if (url.search("about-us") >= 0) {
  $("ul.menu.low li a:nth-child(2)").addClass("active red");
}
```

```css
a.active.red {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-width: 70px;
  color: red !important;
}

a.active.white {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  max-width: 70px;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu low">
  <li><a href="http://myshop.com/" target="_self">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="http://myshop.com/about-us/" target="_self">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://myshop.com/hi" target="_self"><span>Hi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://myshop.com/bye" target="_self"><span>Bye</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you sure its passing the if statement condition? `if (url.search("about-us") >= 0)`

Comment: Yes as I can place an alert there and it only shows on that page,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not applying the nth-child to the correct part of the selector.

Your selector is targeting the `nth-child` that is an `<a>` tag, where as you should be applying it to the `<li>` tag

Try this instead:

```
$("ul.menu.low li:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active red");
```

This will target both 2nd children of both `<ul>`.  If you intend to only target the first ul, then use a descendant selector too:

```
$("ul.menu.low > li:nth-child(2) > a").addClass("active red");
```

This way you will only target the "About" li, and not the "Bye" one too.

Similarly, you could use the `.eq` method to choose the 2nd element, rather than using the CSS selector:

```
$("ul.menu.low > li").eq(2).addClass("active red");
```

Comment: This is a better explained answer, but it should also be targeting `a:first` since there is a nested list with more anchors in the second item.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code

```
$("ul.menu.low > li:nth-child(2) > a").addClass("active red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('.menu.low a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') === window.location.href){
        $(this).addClass('active red');
    }

})
```